# SUM with Two different Criteria in Column and Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

In cell B2, I would like to SUM all of the values that that both are AAA and Original Cost from the source table below. Furthermore, making the formula dynamic for the range A8:E8 will be crucial, as the data order might be changing.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Preferably with an Index and Match formula

Thank you!

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Use a Pivot Table.

Comment: What @ScottCraner said. Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Just do it the easy way.

Comment: Need this as part of a report. Pivot Table won't serve my purpose

Comment: `=SUMIFS(INDEX($C$9:$E$15,0,MATCH(B$1,$C$8:$E$8,0)),$A$9:$A$15,$A2)`

Comment: Thank you Scott, this works perfectly on the sample data. However, it didnt work at all on the actual excel sheet. You think the fact that the data are being imported from a connection plays a role?